# how to read a file and Sum of the numbers in that file in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a file with name `numbs.txt` having numbers `3,1,2` seperated by `line`.
I want to write a java program to read those numbers and print `sum` as `3+1+2=6`.

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Because all the duplicate posts for that (the ones with are cites) are a bit old, I would suggest easy way (and more recent) to achieve that :

```
public static int method1(String path) throws IOException {
    int sum = 0;
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path)))
        sum += Integer.parseInt(line);
    return sum;
}

public static int method2(String path) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path)).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
}
```

`Files.readAllLines(somePath)` returns a `List<String>` so the frst method will iterate with a classic `for each loop`, `parse to Integer` and sum. The second method will do the same with another syntax, using latest API of `Java 8`  : `Streams` (iterate and do same)

---

To use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(method1("numbs.txt"));  // if file is not in same folder
    System.out.println(method2("numbs.txt"));  //use absolute path: C:\users\...\numbs.txt
}
```

Comment: Hmh .. Very kind of you ^^